# How to make blinking button from two images objective c sprite node

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to create blinking button from two images using sprite Kit, now I have :

```
resButt = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed : @"retry.png"]
```

I saw couple posts about how to do it using UIButton, but my question is how to do it in Sprite Kit using objective c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing required is an `SKAction` that changes your sprite's texture (an image applied to geometry).  If you mean "blink" indefinitely, that action must be repeated, and there's an action for that, too.

```
// create textures for the sprite 
UIImage *imageA = [UIImage imageNamed:@"retryA.png"];
UIImage *imageB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"retryB.png"];
SKTexture *textureA = [SKTexture textureWithImage:imageA];
SKTexture *textureB = [SKTexture textureWithImage:imageB];

// create an action that applies the textures in sequence
NSArray *textures = @[textureA, textureB];
SKAction *blink = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.5];

// create an action that repeats the texture sequence
SKAction *blinkForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:blink];

// run it
[myButtonSprite runAction:blinkForever withKey:@"blinkForever"];
```

Forever is a long time, of course, so this begs the question of how to stop blinking.  That's why we added the `withKey:` qualifier to the run action above.  With it, you can refer to the action in order to stop it.

```
[myButtonSprite removeActionForKey:@"blinkForever"];
```